# Find an orthogonal matrix that achieves a given vectorial transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

Given a vector $\vec a\in\mathbb R^n$ and another $\alpha=(\|\vec a\|,0,\dots,0)$, how could I define an orthogonal matrix $M$ such that $M\vec a=\alpha$ and $M^{-1}=M^t$? For $\mathbb R^2$ I tried to use a generic matrix $\; Q=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & c\\b & d\end{array}\right)$ and $M=Orthogonalize(Q)$ using Grahm-Shmidth, but apparently there are no possible $a,b,c,d$ values. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any orthogonal basis $\{w_j\}$, $j=1\ldots n$ such  that $w_1=\vec a/\|\vec a\|$.

Now take another orthogonal basis $\{v_j\}$, $j=1\ldots n$, such that $v_1=\vec \alpha/\|\vec\alpha\|$.

Now build a linear operator $M$ given by $$\forall j\quad Mw_j=v_j.$$

It is an orthogonal operator and $M\vec a=\vec \alpha$.

In terms of matrices, the simpliest case would be to take the matrix $A$ of coordinates of column vectors of the basis $\{w_j\}$, then of possible operators $M$ can be written as $M=A^{-1}$.

Comment: So, since $\alpha=(\|a\|,0,\dots,0)$, I think I could choose $\forall j. v_j=e_j$. By the way, how could I determine the orthogonal basis $\{w_j\}_{1< j\leq n}$ given $w_1=\frac{\vec a}{\|\vec a\|}$? Should I use  Grahm-Shmidth or there is a more easy solution?

Comment: @jackb the most straightforward method is to take any basis and then use Gram-Schmidt. But, in some particular cases one can even guess such a basis. For example, if  $w=(1,0,1)$, the obvious guess is $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I've just started to study linear algebra. If I remember correcly, the basis that should be used in Gram-Schmidt is a basis formed by linear indipendent vectors. How could I define the remaining $\{w_j\}_{j>1}$ given $w_1=\frac{\vec a}{\|\vec a\|}$? Thanks again.

Comment: Ex. Given $a=(2/5,3/5)^t$ and $w_1=e_1$ $w_2=e_2$, I could define a system where $Ma=e_1$ and $M(2/5,-3/5)^t=e_2$, obtaining $M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}5/4 & 5/6 \\ 9/5 & -6/5\end{array}\right)$. By the way I obtain $\theta(a,b)\neq \theta(Ma,Mb)$, where $b=(4/5,3/5)^t$ and $\theta$ is the cosine distance. I know that orthogonal matrices could be used to preserve metric distances: did I do something wrong, or those $M$s could not preserve distances?

Comment: The problem comes from the wrong system you are trying to solve. The vectors you took are not orthogonal. You should take $Ma=e_1$ and $M(-3/5,2/5)^t=e_2$.

Comment: Thanks: I used Grahm-Shmidth to ortogonalize my linear independent vectors and then I applied your method.

Answer (score 0):

use reflection transformation $R = 2uu^T/u^Tu - I$ or $I - 2vv^T/v^Tv$ where $u = a + |a|e_1$ and $v = a - |a|e_1.$

these reflection matrices are sometimes called householder transformations.

Comment: I would like that M is a rotation in $n$D. Are these transformations metric invariant?

Comment: what does metric invariant mean? you can certainly get from $a$ to $|a|e_1$ in two reflections through some intermediate point. you may be able construct a rotation by a sequence of reflections.

Comment: Given a metric $\theta$ such that $\theta(\vec a,\vec b)=k$, I would like to define $M$ such that $\theta(M\vec a,M\vec b)=k$: I think that if $M$ is a rotation then this constraint is met.